# Joining three table using package and cursor

Tags: sql, oracle10g, oracle11g

I am new to sql so i need help in understanding this.

I have  3 tables :-

Table 1 :-  employee no. 
employee name
person_id

Table 2 :- Contact no.
person_id

Table 3 :- Address
person_id

I tried to make a package and use a procedure to define a cursor. now i want to display the contact no ,address and emp number from the tables using joins. i have applied the join condition but am not able to understand how to display the result.

*Package body*

```
create or replace package pacakge_name
    as 
    procedure procedure_name

    declare
    cursor cur_name is select * from table1 join table2 on table1.person_id=table2.person_id join table 3 on table1.person_idd=table3.id;

    var_curname cur_name%rowtype;

    begin

    open cur_name;

    loop
    fetch cur_name into var_curname
    exit
    when cur_name%NOTFOUND;
    end loop;
    close cur_name;
    end;
```

Comment: you tagged this mysql, sql-server and oracle, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: sorry. wrong tags. i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for displaying result to console you have to `dbms_output.put_line(var_curname.fieldname);`

this will be your cursor query:

```
select table2.contact_no,
table3.address,
table1.employee_no
from 
table1,
table2,
table3
where table1.person_id = table2.person_id and
table2.person_id = table3.person_id
```

so your dbms_output.put_line will be

```
dbms_output.put_line(var_curname.contact_no||'-'||var_curname.address||'-'||var_curname.employee_no);
```

Comment: yes but i have joined 3 tables by cursor (select * from table1 join table2 on table1.person_id=table2.person_id join table 3 on table1.person_idd=table3.id)

will dbms_output.put_line(var_curname.fieldname) still work ?

Comment: the normal way of creating package is to create a specification and package body